# Is there a way in factory_girl to get attributes_for and create for the same instance element?

Tags: ruby, factory, factory-bot, machinist

If I want to create and instance using "create" build strategy and then want to use "attributes_for" build strategy for verification, is it possible to do? And if I use sequences in the factory? Is it possible in Machinist gem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not quite sure I fully understand.  And I'm not a user of machinist.  But it sounds like you just want to do something like this.

```
@attributes = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:my_object)
my_object = MyObject.create(@attributes)
my_object.some_property.should == @attributes[:some_property]
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution [John Hinnegan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5208386/745359) suggest is sound, but you better use the `FactoryGirl.create` method for object initialization, because it will usually give you a valid Object. For example a `after(:create)` won't be called if you use `MyObject.new`.

```
@attributes = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:my_object)
my_object = FactoryGirl.create(:my_object, @attributes)
expect(my_object.some_property).to eq @attributes[:some_property]
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this post, just wanted to add that the class is FactoryGirl

```
@user_attributes = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:super_user)
```